# Move_uploaded_files() não passa o arquivo

Tags: php

Estou montando um sistema de troca de arquivos aqui para a empresa, mas estou com um erro no mínimo estranho. Alguns arquivos, principalmente PDF, ele nem passa para o `SalvarArquivo.php`. A variável simplesmente chega vazia.

O que notei é que esses arquivos são um "pouco" maiores, algo na casa de 15 a 30mb. Arquivos menores funcionam normalmente. O pior que a intenção é poder fazer upload de até 5GB....

**O que tentei:**

PHP.ini - Setei o max_upload para 1 GB e o tempo para 3600 segundos;
phpmyadmin.conf - setei também para 1GB e o tempo para 3600 segundos.

Quando tentei por um `catch exception`  quando retornava o erro no `move_uploaded_file()` apenas retornava "Não foi possível mover o arquivo".

Segue o form:

```
             <form id="cadastro" name="cadastro" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="SalvarArquivo.php" onsubmit="salvar.disabled = true; salvar.value='AGUARDE...'; return true;">
                 <center><input type="email" name ="email_remetente" id="email_remetente" placeholder="Digite o seu email" required>
                         <input type="email" name ="email_destinatario" id="email_destinatario" placeholder="Digite o email do destinatário" required><br>
                         <input type="file" id="arquivo" name="arquivo" size="60" required>
                         Andamento:<br><progress id="progressbar" value="0" max="100"></progress><br>

                         <input type = "submit" id="salvar" name="salvar" onclick="javascript:upload();" value = "ENVIAR!" class="btn">

                 </center>
            </form>
```

E esse é o PHP:

```
<?php
/* Arquivo: SalvarArquivo.php
 *
 * Este script salva o arquivo enviado e gera o link para envio por email.
 *
 * Dados de Origem: index.php
 *
 */

// Dados do banco
include "js/conn.php";

//Gera nome aleatório para cada arquivo
$tamanho = mt_rand(5,9);
$all_str = "abcdefghijlkmnopqrstuvxyzwABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
$nome = "";
for ($i = 0;$i <= $tamanho;$i++){
   $nome .= $all_str[mt_rand(0,61)];
}
//endereços de emails para envio e do remetente
$email_remetente = $_POST['email_remetente'];
$email_destinatario = $_POST['email_destinatario'];
//ip do cliente
$ip_envio = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

// Pasta onde o arquivo vai ser salvo
$_UP['pasta'] = 'BASE/';

// Tamanho máximo do arquivo (em Bytes)
$_UP['tamanho'] = 52428800; // 5GB

// Array com as extensões permitidas
$_UP['extensoes'] = array('pdf', 'doc', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'docx', 'html', 'zip', 'rar', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'iso');
echo $_UP['extensoes'];
// Renomeia o arquivo? (Se true, o arquivo será salvo como .jpg e um nome único)
$_UP['renomeia'] = false;

// Array com os tipos de erros de upload do PHP
$_UP['erros'][0] = 'Não houve erro';
$_UP['erros'][1] = 'O arquivo no upload é maior do que o limite do PHP';
$_UP['erros'][2] = 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho especifiado no HTML';
$_UP['erros'][3] = 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente';
$_UP['erros'][4] = 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo';

// Verifica se houve algum erro com o upload. Se sim, exibe a mensagem do erro
if ($_FILES['arquivo']['error'] != 0) {
  die("Não foi possível fazer o upload, erro:
  " . $_UP['erros'][$_FILES['arquivo']['error']]);
exit; // Para a execução do script
}

// Caso script chegue a esse ponto, não houve erro com o upload e o PHP pode continuar

// Faz a verificação da extensão do arquivo
$extensao = @strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['arquivo']['name'])));
if (array_search($extensao, $_UP['extensoes']) === false) {
            //enviar aviso de extensão inválida
            ?>
            <script language="JavaScript">
            <!--
            alert("Extensão <? print($extensao); ?> não permitida.");
            window.location = '/upload/';
            //-->
            </script>
            <?
            exit;
}

// Faz a verificação do tamanho do arquivo
else if ($_UP['tamanho'] < $_FILES['arquivo']['size']) {
  echo "O arquivo enviado é muito grande, envie arquivos de até 5 GB.";
}
// O arquivo passou em todas as verificações, hora de tentar movê-lo para a pasta
else {
// Primeiro verifica se deve trocar o nome do arquivo
if ($_UP['renomeia'] == true) {
// Cria um nome baseado no UNIX TIMESTAMP atual e com extensão .jpg
$nome_final = time().'.jpg';

} else {

//Grava o numero mais a extensão verificada no inicio do arquivo
$nome_final = $nome.'.'.$extensao;
// Mantém o nome original do arquivo
//$nome_final = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
}

// Depois verifica se é possível mover o arquivo para a pasta escolhida
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $_UP['pasta'] . $nome_final)) {
// Upload efetuado com sucesso, exibe uma mensagem e um link para o arquivo

//link para o arquivo enviado
$server = "http://pcn-sig02.peccin.local/upload/";
$anexo = $server.$_UP['pasta'].$nome_final;

include ("EnviarEmail.php");
//echo '<br><a href="'.$anexo.'">Baixar anexo</a>';

} else {

// Não foi possível fazer o upload, provavelmente a pasta está incorreta
echo "Não foi possível enviar o arquivo, tente novamente";
echo $_FILES['arquivo']['error'];
}

}// FECHA ELSE VERIFICAÇÕES
?>
```

Comment: Já tentou pelo htacess ?

Comment: No else do erro coloque `error_get_last();` essa funçao vai retornar um array, veja se devolve algo relacionado ao erro.

Comment: A foma mais fácil de verificar se é realmente o tamanho do arquivo o problema é modificar o .htacess adicionando essas [linhas](http://pastebin.com/9w7zQmxT)

Comment: Victor Gomes, adicionei suas linhas em um htacess e deu certo. Por algum motivo ele não aceitou o que setei no php.ini. Muito obrigado! @rray coloquei o error_get_last() mas ele só retornou "Array".

Comment: Da um assim `print_r(error_get_last());`